# java repaint() and initializing objects

Tags: java, object, animation, paint, instantiation

I have a class that is supposed to simulate a firework animation using paintComponent and repaint() the problem that I have detected is that a "Firework" is newly initialized 
each time the method is invoked so the projectileTime field of the firework is reset to zero (as specified in the constructor) each time. Where is the appropriate place to instantiate a firework object so that the projectileTime field is incremented appropriately? (In this class or in another class)
see code:

```
public class FireworkComponent extends JComponent {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6733926341300224321L;
private double time;

public FireworkComponent(){
time=0;
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.translate(0, this.getHeight());

    Firework f= new Firework(this.getWidth()/2,0,73,90,Color.red,5);
    f.addFirework(75,35,Color.BLUE,6);
    f.addFirework(75, 155, Color.green, 6);

    time+=.1;

    Point point=f.addTime(.1);
    g.fillOval(point.x, (-point.y),15,15);

    try{
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("sleep");
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that code would not compile.  Please consider posting an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) in future, and please use the common form of indenting code, as opposed to that mish-mash.

Comment: Don't call `sleep()` in a method intended to paint the GUI!  Instead create a Swing `Timer` that calls `repaint()` at regular intervals.

Comment: Never call `Thread.sleep(...)` on the main Swing thread, the EDT, and never ever, ***EVER*** call `Thread.sleep(...)` within paint or paintComponent unless you want your graphics to come to a complete and utter grinding halt.  **edit:** too late!

Answer (score 2):

First of all get rid of the Thread.sleep() from the paintComponent() method.

Then you need to define properties of the Firework component that change over time.

Finally, you would use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation of the fireworks. Every time the Timer fires you would update the component properties and then invoke repaint() on the component.

Answer (score 2):

please

- don't add `Firework f= new Firework(this.getWidth()/2,0,73,90,Color.red,5);` inside Paint Graphics2D, you have to prepare this before
- don't delay you paint by using `Thread.sleep(int);`, for Graphics2D is there `javax.swing.Timer`, but you have to initialize `paintComponent()` by using Timer, not stop to painting inside the Paint body
- not sure if somehow working `Point point=f.addTime(.1);`

EDIT

for animations is there [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805168/java-jsplitpane-duplicates-top-panels-contents-to-bottom-panel-when-timer-is-ac/6805865#6805865)

Comment: when you say "prepare before" you mean in another class or in this class's constructor?

Comment: @trs see my edit, that would be base for that, prepared Objects moved throught screen by using javax.swing.Timer, carrefully with that, otherwise your animations would be freeze or hanging on the screen

Comment: *"in another class or in this class's constructor?"*  Either would work, the important thing is not to create them again & again in a method that loops (like `paintComponent()`).

Answer (score 2):

Store the `Firework` as a class level attribute and instantiate it in the `FireworkComponent` constructor.